# Experiences using protocol-buffers for eeprom?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I've seen the [protocol-buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). They look very interesting. Does someone use them to store data to an eeprom? What are your experiences?

The eeproms are small (<128kB), so my way was to put all my data to a byte array by knowing the address-offset of each data element. By using c++ you have then be carefully with padding.

Comment: `Your system's memory allocator may not be well-optimized for allocating lots of small objects from multiple threads. Try using Google's tcmalloc instead.` - this might be a problem when using embedded devices or EEPROM - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial PS I wouldn't use C++ on an embedded computer.

Comment: @paladin Thank you for your thougts. I saw one more project which could be compatible to protocol-buffers: [protobuf-c](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c). So I could may run C# code on my desktop and C code on my embedded device?